# Firebase Cloud Messaging user sending notification to another user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am designing an application which has two types of user, vendor and Customer. Vendor delivers product and customers order them.

I want to send a notification when a Customer orders something from a vendor. Only that vendor should get notification. Similarly, when the product is mark delivered by vendor, a notification should appear on the customer side.

I was thinking of storing tokens in Firebase Database in the profile for each user, so let's say a customer orders something, he can retrieve Vendor's token so a notification appears on Vendor's side.

I recently came across this answer [Cannot resolve symbol com.google.firebase.messaging.Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57059108/cannot-resolve-symbol-com-google-firebase-messaging-message/57063431#57063431)

which says it's not possible to do so, without admin SDK, which can't be used in Android App.

What options do I have for this use case?

Do I have to create my own server? Is there anyway to do this with just Firebase?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a firebase message to topic from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948318/how-to-send-a-firebase-message-to-topic-from-android)

Comment: No, it is sending notification to a topic which are limited to 2000. So If I map one topic to user, number of users should not exceed 2000. Also as the comment says, only admin can send Notification that way. I need user to user notification

Comment: 2000 limit is for One app instance not whole app, one app instance its mean every app on one device can subscribe to 2000 topics , 

show link here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Answer (score 0):

I fell into this same problem before and I solved it by using a token which is the same as in my **national number** application through the **topicKey** when the employee sends to the user or I already created the **topicKey** for the user when he is in the process of registering in the application which is the **national number**.

When the employee accepts the user’s request, add the order number to the **topicKey**, which is the **national number**.

In your problem you can use the phone number because it is a unique code and create a **topicKey** based on it.

> I hope I understood your problem correctly and I apologize for the spelling errors because it is not my native language.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you created a topic for every user. There are limits to number of topics that can be created for an app. 2000 topics per app I think. If the number of users exceed 2000, it will no longer work.